# Multi choice parameter data type in ArcMap Toolbox

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.3, python-script-tool, parameters

I'm a beginner ArcMap user.

I created a toolbox in ArcMap/mytoolboxes which will run an specific Python script from my hard drive.

In my python script I need user to choose between 2 options. I want to add a 2 choice radio buttons in running toolbox page. If user choose one of those radio buttons, the other will be deselected and vice-versa. The problem is that I do not know which data type for this parameter is right for me.

[image: Parameter types]

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58396/how-to-add-radio-buttons-to-python-script-tool-dialog) is still the case. Radio buttons are not an option. Use Boolean for a check-box. This will allow for two choices (checked vs unchecked).

[image]

[image]

Another option is to use String and add a filter for a drop-down list.

[image]

[image]